# Using Run Keywords on multiple keywords which are stored in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

This is not working in Robot Framework :

```
${x}=   Input Text    id:userid    12456484    AND    Input Text    id:pwd    abcd123
Run Keywords   ${x}
```

giving error:

> **No keyword with name 'Input Text    id:userid    12456484    AND    Input Text    id:pwd    abcd123' found.**

So I want to achieve is making a custom keyword and passing multiple **steps** to it, each step will have a keyword and its arguments, like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***

Test  1  "Some test cases"  Input Text  id:userid  124567
...  AND  Input Text  id:pwd  abc123

*** Keywords ***

Test
  [Arguments]  ${StepNo}  ${StepDes}  @{varargs}
  ${x}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=${SPACE*4}    @{varargs}
  Run Keywords  ${x}
```

This gives the same error described above. Here is the screenshot of the error :

[image]

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Can you explain why the second example does not work for you? What is it you expect that `${x}` will hold after the code line is executed. By only telling us what doesn't work, we're left guessing what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra I added the extra details.

Comment: The code you posted will not give the error you say it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley It does, I am adding the screenshot of the error to the question.

Comment: The code in the screenshot doesn't match the code in the question. The code in the question gives a different error.  It throws `No keyword with name '1' found.` and `No keyword with name 'AND' found.` along with a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended use for `Run Keywords` is set in the [documentation for the keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords) as follows:

> This keyword is mainly useful in setups and teardowns when they need
>   to take care of multiple actions and creating a new higher level user
>   keyword would be an overkill.

Outside of this scope I've not had any real use for this keyword myself. In addition the problem you're also facing is that the `AND` is special:

> Notice that the AND control argument must be used explicitly and
>   cannot itself come from a variable.

In the event that you want to have a variable number of keywords with arguments to be executed, then another issue you're going to run into that the `Run Keywords  @{keywords}` construct does not support keywords with arguments.

So, in conclusion, create a custom keyword for your user scenario and place each necessary keyword in there with their appropriate arguments. If flexibility is needed, then use `Run Keyword if`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to store those keywords in a variable?

Why not use them inside a keyword, like:

```
***Test Cases***
Test
    My awesome Keyword

***Keywords***
My awesome Keyword
          Run Keywords    Input Text    id:userid    12456484    AND    Input Text    id:pwd    abcd123
```

Comment: Please ask questions through comments and only provide an answer when the technical problem is clear.